# MongoDB database design for timeseries data

Tags: python, mongodb, database-design, time-series

Bit of a Mongo noob here looking to to get some feedback on whether I am thinking too much 'MySQL', and if so, how to think differently about tackling this problem.

For a project, I have been trying to use MongoDB to store individual user behavior on social/video platforms. For example, on Reddit I am looking to track users who comment on frontpage post from a set of subreddits at regular intervals, and then see if there activity overlaps with other subreddits. After collecting the data, I am looking to store it where individual users are single documents, looking as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57a9af8172cad6fcaa916963"),
    "name" : "example_user_1",
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "subreddit" : ObjectId("57a9af2336a21c2f343dccad"),
            "thread" : ObjectId("57a9af2436a21c2f343dccae"),
            "time" : ISODate("2016-08-09T12:25:05.061Z")
        },
        {
            "subreddit" : ObjectId("57a9af2336a21c2f343dccad"),
            "thread" : ObjectId("57a9af2436a21c2f343dccae"),
            "time" : ISODate("2016-08-09T12:25:05.061Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, these are irregular timeseries datasets, where whenever I see a user commenting, I $push his location and time to the 'data' array. The subreddit and thread ObjectID's reference back to another collection where I have stored some of the meta data of these subreddits and threads.

For my questions:

1) Is this the 'correct way' to use MongoDB for this purpose? It has a relational feel to it, but I am not sure how to store all this data in another way (while keeping it easy to query aggregate user behavior).

2) Currently, I am using ObjectID's to store subreddit and thread ID's that are referenced from another collection. Using a 12-byte ObjectID, however, feels inefficient to reference subreddits (in MySQL, a tinyint would suffice here which is 2 byte per data point). I read everywhere that auto increment is a big no no in MongoDB, but does that apply here?

I have read both [this](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb) article on timeseries data with regular intervals (which is not applicable in my case), and [this](https://bluxte.net/musings/2015/01/21/efficient-storage-non-periodic-time-series-mongodb/) article about irregular timeseries, which is not an ideal option for me, as my timeseries can be so irregular that creating segments with a start and end date might prove less efficient than adding dates per serie.